# Summation with jump indices like 1,4,6,9?

Tags: summation

I is easy to enter

$ \sum_{s=1}^{n}k(s) $

But how can I enter

$ \sum_{s=1,3}k(s) $

?

When I try it, Mathematica says

```
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

Also the following didn't work.

$\sum_{s=1,3}^{3}k(s)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/Sum.html):

> $\sum _i^{i_{\max }} f$ is by default interpreted as `Sum[f {`$i$, $i_{\max }$`}]`

so we can abuse this:
[image]

You can use `Sequence` to provide `di` too because:

> $\sum _{i=i_{\min }}^{i_{\max }} f$ is by default interpreted as  `Sum[f {`$i$, $i_{\min }$, $i_{\max }$`}]`

[image]

---

[ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) has found **undocumented** but useful pattern that is also interpreted:

> $\sum _{spec} f$ is by default interpreted as  `Sum[f, spec]`

[image]

Comment: Using `{i,1,5,2}` instead of `i=1` works too

Comment: @ssch Good point, definitely cleaner than `Sequence` :)

Comment: @Kuba What exactly do you mean by your "`Sequence`" solution? When I evaluate `Sum[i, {i, {i = 1, Sequence[5, 2]}}]` I get `8` in *Mathematica* 8.0.4. Please clarify.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov according to the documentation, solution with `Sequence` is equivalent to `Sum[i, {i, 1, Sequence[5, 2]}]` not to the one you've provided.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, it is clear now. +1